# (mongoose) put method does not work

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am creating web API using mongoose.

POST and GET work, but I have no idea how to implement PUT method in mongoose.

Here is what I created:

board.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const config = require('../config/database');

const BoardSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String
    },
    position: {
        type: [String]
    }
});

const Board = module.exports = mongoose.model('boards', BoardSchema);

module.exports.getBoardById = function (id, callback)
{
    Board.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.addBoard = function (newBoard, callback)
{
    newBoard.save(callback);
}

module.exports.updateBoard = function (newBoard, callback)
{
    newBoard.save(callback);
}
```

users.js

```
router.put('/board/:id', (req, res, next) =>
{
    let newBoard = new Board({
        _id: req.params.id,
        position: req.body.position
    });

    Board.updateBoard(newBoard, (err, board) =>
    {
        if (err)
        {
            res.json({ newBoard: newBoard, success: false, msg: "Failed to update board" });
        }
        else
        {
            res.json({ newBoard: newBoard, success: true, msg: "Board added" });
        }
    });
});;
```

Here, in the board.js, I created methods for adding a new board and updating to existing board. .addBoard is working correctly and am able to test it using Postman. But, .updateBoard adds the data when the data does not exist, but does not update any data and returns false as response (just like POST does). Is there any way I can make the PUT method works?

Thank you!

Comment: Mongo update is `.update( query, update,[options] );` Mongoose is the same. So for example:  `Board.update( {_id: req.params.id }, newBoard );`   - But if you want to use save you can do that too. `const board = Board.findById(...); board.something = "abc123"; board.save();` but if you replace the id and save, mongo will probably see that as a new object, and not an update.

Comment: please [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408243/trouble-with-put-request-using-node-js-express-angular-and-mongodb) hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you using save method while updating?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const config = require('../config/database');

const BoardSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String
    },
    position: {
        type: [String]
    }
});

const Board = module.exports = mongoose.model('boards', BoardSchema);

module.exports.getBoardById = function (id, callback)
{
    Board.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.addBoard = function (newBoard, callback)
{
    newBoard.save(callback);
}

module.exports.updateBoard = function (condition, update, callback)
{
    Board.update(condition,update,callback);
}
```

in controller

```
router.put('/board/:id', (req, res, next) =>
{
    let newBoard = new Board({
        _id: req.params.id,
        position: req.body.position
    });

    Board.updateBoard({ _id: req.params.id } ,newBoard, (err, board) =>
    {
        if (err)
        {
            res.json({ newBoard: newBoard, success: false, msg: "Failed to update board" });
        }
        else
        {
            res.json({ newBoard: newBoard, success: true, msg: "Board added" });
        }
    });
});
```

try this.

Answer (score 3):

Please let me know if this works for you! I want to introduce you to http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyidandupdate_findByIdAndUpdate

```
router.put('/board/:id', (req, res) => {
  const {id: _id} = req.params // Assigning id to _id which is a es6 feature. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
  const {position} = req.body

  const newBoard = {
    _id,
    position
  }

  Board.findByIdAndUpdate(
    _id,
    newBoard,
    (err, updatedBoard) => {
      if (err) {
        res.json({
          newBoard,
          success: false,
          msg: 'Failed to update board'
        })
      } else {
        res.json({newBoard, success: true, msg: 'Board added'})
      }
    }
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using req.body i think you are trying to call a put request from a form (sometimes happens with AJAX requests also). For doing that use [method-overide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/method-override). And set the xhr header as given in the documentation. This will surely work.